# vlookup using awk and bash: Slow for huge data

Tags: bash, awk, vlookup

I have a master data of id and name. They are almost 13000 entries. The file name is `master.txt`

```
id   name
1: name1
2: test
3: fin
4: miar
```

Now i have another list of data with `id` and `someproperty`. Each id can be coming up multiple times. The data is 74000 entries. `person_entries.txt`
Eg data:

```
id  property
1: somevalue001
2: somevalue002
2: somevalue003
1: somevalue004
```

Now i have to do something like vlookup to add name instead of id

Eg:

```
name    property
name1: somevalue001
test: somevalue002
test: somevalue003
name1: somevalue004
```

I am trying the below script `vlookup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    IFS=$'\n';
    myarr=(`echo $line | awk -f break_data.awk`)
    #This will break each data into two lines (id and property which then can be stored as array)

    awk -v var="${myarr[0]}:" -v var2="${myarr[1]}" -f find_data.awk master.txt
    # here we pass the id and property to awk as variables. It will search for id in the master.txt and print name and propert
done < "person_entries.txt"
```

`break_data.awk`

```
# INPUT
# 1: name1

# OUTPUT
# 1
# name1

BEGIN{
    FS=": "
}
{
    for(i=1;i<NF+1;i++)
    {
        print $i
    }
}
END{
}
```

`find_data.awk`

```
#THIS WILL SEARCH THE ID: IN EACH LINE OF break_data2.awk
#WHEN IT FINDS THEN IT WILL PRING THE NAME AnD PROPERTY

BEGIN{
    FS=": "
    #print(var)
}
{
    s=index($0, var)
    if(s != 0){
        print $2": "var2
    }
    else{
        next
    }
}
END{
}
```

When i run
`sh vlookup.sh`

Its taking a lot of time.

Excel can be faster than this.

**ANSWER CODE WRITTEN FOR MY UNDERSTANDING:**

```
$ awk '                # use awk
{ 
  if(NR==FNR) 
  {              # process first file
    a[$1]=$2           # hash to a array id is key, name value
    next               # process next record without executing following code
  } else
  {                      # process second file
    print a[$1]":",$2  # output name (the value of) from array a and property
  }

}' master person
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it. You may have to tweak the `:` thing a bit, though (see the header) and decide what happens if there is no match:

```
$ awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print a[$1]":",$2}' master person
```

Output:

```
name: property
name1: somevalue001
test: somevalue002
test: somevalue003
name1: somevalue004
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '                # use awk
NR==FNR {              # process first file
    a[$1]=$2           # hash to a array id is key, name value
    next               # process next record without executing following code
}
{                      # process second file
    print a[$1]":",$2  # output name (the value of) from array a and property
}' master person       # of the second file, colon in the middle
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as fast as `awk` but this is faster than your bash code.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS= read -r master_head < master.txt
IFS= read -r person_head < person_entries.txt
printf '%s: %s\n' "${master_head##* }" "${person_head##* }"

while IFS= read -ru8 master; do
  while IFS= read -ru9 person; do
    if [[ ${master%% *} == ${person%% *} ]]; then
      printf '%s: %s\n' "${person##* }" "${master##* }"
    fi
  done 9< <(tail -n+2 master.txt)
done 8< <(tail -n+2 person_entries.txt)
```